# Configuring syslogd to accept remote connections on OS X Mountain Lion and assign them a category

Tags: macos, networking, mac, osx-mountain-lion, syslog

From [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510563/how-to-start-syslogd-server-on-mac-to-accept-remote-logging-messages) here on Stack Exchange, I have discovered that it's pretty easy to enable syslogd on Lion or Mountain Lion to accept incoming connections.

```
cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :Sockets:NetworkListener dict" com.apple.syslogd.plist
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :Sockets:NetworkListener:SockServiceName string syslog" com.apple.syslogd.plist
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :Sockets:NetworkListener:SockType string dgram" com.apple.syslogd.plist
sudo launchctl unload com.apple.syslogd.plist
sudo launchctl load com.apple.syslogd.plist
```

The issue I have however is that when my router is sending messages to syslogd, they come up in the Console on OS X as coming from Unknown - e.g:

```
5/3/13 9:19:40.000 AM Unknown[-1]: [WAN-IN-6-A]IN=eth2 OUT=eth0 SRC=141.133.142.260 DST=10.0.00.10 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=30298 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=60553 DPT=443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Whereas a log message from the local machine specifies a sender:
    5/3/13 7:38:20.155 AM kdc[67]: LKDC referral to the real LKDC realm name

Running tcpdump on the remote log host shows that the messages are being sent with more information than is shown in Console:

```
    router.example.com.38236 > server.example.com.syslog: SYSLOG, length: 258
Facility kernel (0), Severity warning (4)
Msg: May  3 09:12:39 router kernel: [WAN-LOCAL-default-D]IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=dc:ca:fe:ba:be:17:00:21:a0:ce:66:d9:07:00 SRC=86.86.123.381 DST=130.168.365.128 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=39 ID=26555 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46635 DPT=62615 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

09:12:45.557613 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 286)

Can anyone direct me to how to configure syslog on OS X Mountain Lion server to recognise the sender in incoming log messages and categorise them appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's too late for the OP, but I can report on my recent experience with OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

Looks like you can NOT configure syslogd in OS X to *directly* recognise the sender. In fact, once the log messages have been received into ASL (Apple System Log), the only way to recognise them is because they have some nonsensical keys: PID is 0xFFFFFFFF+1, GID and UID are 0xFFFFFFFF+2. 
Of course that anomaly allows you to *indirectly* recognise the UDP messages, so you can just grab the ones with such keys. But still you won't be able to tell apart log messages coming from 2 different UDP sources.

Could we do something to the messages before they get into ASL? I have not found any way, and I don't think there is a possibility, because the debug mode in syslogd/ASL shows that the message parsing is already done by an ASL function.

Note that I did my tests using a DD-WRT router (which is a Linux) as the UDP syslog source, and I did not try checking directly the contents of the UDP packets; so it could be that the problem is in DD-WRT sending malformed packets. ... though I doubt it.

Also, I would say that OS X's syslogd/ASL is rather complicated and buggy (I sent a bug report already). So I would recommend to pass on them and try syslog-ng. That will be my next step.

In case you still want to try with OS X's syslogd, I wrote on the whole setup in [my blog](http://hmijailblog.blogspot.com/2015/03/using-os-xs-syslogd-to-receive-log.html), including how to dump all the UDP-incoming messages into their own auto-rotated log file.